# How to find all values in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have a json like this:

```
{ "fwdTrackGeom": "MULTILINESTRING ((56.307041507017 58.011219723083, 56.307961164317 58.010033333358, 56.308853999526 58.008881008358), (56.308853999526 58.008881008358, 56.309011612988 58.008414442093, 56.309042139956 58.008156999171, 56.309008293909 58.007831344383, 56.308806969015 58.007403489114, 56.308573457613 58.007075104002, 56.307891858088 58.006361480718, 56.306619854144 58.004996722377))" }
```

I make a string with

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *path = [json objectForKey:@"fwdTrackGeom"];
```

And now I need to make `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from path. Who can explain how do this?

Comment: The documentation can explain it pretty well. Look for the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method, in particular.

Comment: Yes, when all else fails RTFM (read the fine manual).

Comment: @H2CO3 It looks like there's more to it than a simple split: there seems to be some structure going on inside that `MULTILINESTRING` thingy.

Comment: You split twice, once with "," to get the pairs, then again with " " to split each pair.  (And you're on your own with those embedded "()".)

Comment: (I'd be tempted to go through several character replacement cycles to convert it into legit JSON, then parse that.)

Comment: (I kinda suspect that the OP omitted some lines or something, though, since the parens are mismatched.)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well, still seems a trivial enough task to extract the two (or something) levels of parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, i thought there is better method than separating.